# How to convert SMBUS example code to fully compatible MCU, STM32L4R5 -> STM32L496

Tags: stm32, smbus, stm32cubeide, pmbus

Has anyone been able to use the STM32 SMBUS/PMBUS examples codes, and successfully port it to another compatible mcu?

If so what was the steps taken for the conversion?

(Currently trying to flash STM32L4R5- Nuleo SMBUS example code onto the STM32L496- Nucleo.

Any guidance would be truly appreciated. Thank you.